# PS if system manufacturer then run

Tags: windows, powershell

I currently have 2 different PC manufacturers. I am wanting to have powershell pull the system manufacturer then run a program/script. I can't seem to pull only CsManufacturer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of info lives in WMI--Windows Management Instrumentation--which you can get in PowerShell with the `Get-WmiObject` command.

This will get you started:

```
$manufacturer = (gwmi win32_computersystem).Manufacturer
"this pc is a $manufacturer PC"

if ($manufacturer -like "Dell*"){
    #do stuff here
    "this must be a dell!"
}
```

Which would result in this when run on a Dell Laptop,

> this pc is a Dell Inc. PC

> this must be a dell!

Comment: Just a note that `Get-WmiObject` is not available on PS Core versions.  Use `Get-CimInstance` or `gcim` instead of `Get-WmiObject` to maintain forward compatibility with PS Core.

Comment: Also worthy of note is that `get-wmiobject` will only work on Windows machines.  If a user had a dell laptop with Ubuntu on it, and they were using PowerShell, they'd also need `Get-CimInstance`